# Odd regular expression request in .NET for renaming files (increment matches)

Tags: .net, regex

Is the following file output possiable using nothing but a regular expression in .NET? i.e. Regex.Replace

**Original File name convention:**

ISBN_ChapterNumber_TrackNumber.Extension (9999999999999_01_01.mp3)

9999999999999_01_01.mp3
9999999999999_01_02.mp3
9999999999999_01_03.mp3
9999999999999_02_01.mp3
9999999999999_02_02.mp3
9999999999999_02_03.mp3
9999999999999_03_01.mp3
9999999999999_03_02.mp3
9999999999999_03_03.mp3
9999999999999_04_01.mp3
9999999999999_04_02.mp3
9999999999999_04_03.mp3

**Output File name convention**:

VendorPrefix_TrackNumber_ISBN_Extension (aaa_001_9999999999999.mp3)

aaa_001_9999999999999.mp3
aaa_002_9999999999999.mp3
aaa_003_9999999999999.mp3
aaa_004_9999999999999.mp3
aaa_005_9999999999999.mp3
aaa_006_9999999999999.mp3
aaa_007_9999999999999.mp3
aaa_008_9999999999999.mp3
aaa_009_9999999999999.mp3
aaa_010_9999999999999.mp3
aaa_011_9999999999999.mp3
aaa_012_9999999999999.mp3

I have a data driven file renaming class when accepts an input (original file name), search pattern, and a replacement pattern. The return value is then used to rename the file. 

I could easily write a new method to handle this specific vendor but I'm trying to keep everything data driven as much as possible. So the code stays clean and I'm not constantly releasing a version each time.

Comment: 01 to 12 how can that be done through regex....regex cant do arithmetic....rest all replacement can be done

Comment: So the `TrackNumber` in the output isn't the same as the `TrackNumber`  in the original? How are they supposed to map? Is the `TrackNumber` in the output just incremental? Does the input need to be sorted first (by ISBN, then chapter, then track)?

Comment: `using nothing but a regular expression` why the restriction? Use whatever tools will get the job done.

Comment: The current listed data has a base 3 conversion. Dunno why, but its `NewTrackNumber = (ChapterNumber-1)*3 + TrackNumber` . Is this intended ?

Comment: Yes, the output is strictly incremental (sorted by ISBN, chapter, then track). I agree Matt, just wanted to throw the idea out there. I was trying to avoid vendor specific logic.